# Reading dollar amounts

Tags: grammaticality, numbers

I have a question regarding reading dollar amounts. At this store, I saw some scrunchies on sale for $5 per dozen.

Should I say,

> These scrunchies is a five dollar per dozen item.

or is this completely incorrect? Should I reword everything into something like this:

> These scrunchies are priced at five dollars per dozen.

Comment: In the later two sentences, *is/ are* compares 'five dollars' to 'amount/ price' -- 'five dollars' as an amount is singular, 'five dollars' as the price, again, is singular. Lucky you, it could be more confusing actually. :)

Comment: In the first case, *is/ are* refers to 'these scrunchies', plural. As such, the correct sentence would be 'These scrunchies **are** ...'

Comment: I removed your second question because it had nothing whatsoever to do with the first (and was a duplicate of an older question to boot). Please do not post several unrelated questions as one, and please search the site before posting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

lets make it even simpler:

> 'The scrunchies **are** 5 dollars per/a dozen' 
>  
>   or
>   'These/Those scrunchies are (priced at) 5 dollars a/per dozen'

Have a look at the [subject verb agreement. (example 8 will help)](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/)

And since its a price and not prices (and its 5 dollars not one) we would say:

> Is 5 dollars really the right price?

Comment: Or even "12 for 5 bucks."

Comment: How about the last two examples, then? I'm not sure if dollars amounts should be plural or singular. It sounds weird either way for some reason.

Comment: @Pato, for your second question, imagine turning the question around, "Is/are the price really five dollars?". There's only one price, so you need "is" instead of "are".

Comment: @ThePhoton +1 for the ans